# Ordinal-indexed exponentation

Tags: ordinals

I have read from somewhere that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is uncountable.

However, I have also read from somewhere else that $2^\omega=\omega$.

Do the above statements contradict with each other?

In particular, I would like to see a proof of the latter statement.

Comment: The statement that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is a fact from [cardinal arithmetic](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/cardinals.htm) and the statement that $2^{\omega} = \omega$ is a fact from [ordinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks, edited my question to make it clear what I am asking.

Comment: There are several equivalent ways of defining the ordinal exponentiation $2^{\omega}.$ One is these ways is that it is the supremum of $\{2^{n}: \; n < \omega \}$ (the limit ordinal case of ordinal exponentiation [defined by transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Exponentiation)), and for this formulation the result is immediate.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I think I'm getting it, thanks.

Comment: I have seen the claim (and believe it) that many set theory textbooks have (on separate pages) $|2^\omega|=|\omega|, \omega=\aleph_0, 2^{\aleph_0} \gt \aleph_0$.  The key is the difference in the exponentiation operation.  $\omega$ is considered an ordinal, so $2^\omega$ uses ordinal exponentiation while $\aleph_0$ is a cardinal so we use cardinal exponentiation.

Comment: @RossMillikan I fail to see how this claim relates to the question.

Comment: The point is that, as you say, these three statement seem contradictory.  I was updating as you were typing.  The key to resolving the contradiction is to recognize that there are two different exponentiations being used.  I didn't notice that the answer was yours.  You have it right.

Answer (score 2):

The statements do not contradict with each other. Although the **set** $\aleph_0$ is identical to the **set** $\omega$, the operation "exponentiation" is different in the two statements, one being cardinal exponentiation, one being ordinal exponentiation.

Intuitively, $2^{\aleph_0}$ is the cartesian product $\displaystyle\prod_{n \in \aleph_0}2$, where [$2 = \{0,1\}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers), and $2^\omega$ is the order-type of the cartesian product $\displaystyle\prod_{n \in \omega}2$ with [**finite support**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) under the [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). It is the finite support which makes the cardinality of $2^\omega$ the same as $\omega$.

Formally, $2^{\aleph_0}$ is the set of functions from $\aleph_0$ to $2$, and can easily biject with the power set of $\aleph_0$, which, by [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem)
 is greater than $\aleph_0$. $2^\omega$ is defined as $\sup \{2^n \mid n < \omega\}$. All elements in $\{2^n \mid n < \omega\}$ is finite and strictly increasing, and the set is countably infinite, so the supremum is $\omega$, so $2^\omega = \omega$.